# How can I have one login page for one set of people and another page for a different set of people?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have requirement that one type of user login with a regular user name and password (Method A), and another type login by choosing a value from a dropdown box and then inputting a password (Method B).

Method A users get taken to one part of the site (Part A), Method B to a different one (Part B).

My first thought would be that the controllers for each part should have their own login form, but I can only see a way to set up one form, that is I have put

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/PartA/Login" />
</authentication>
```

into web.config. I tried adding an additional web.config for the Part B views, but it gets ignored: I get sent to the login area for Part A.

I've also tried adding a `location` element:

```xml
<location path="PartB">
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/PartB/Login" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>   
</location>
```

But that gives me a parser error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Is there a way to configure the system to redirect the login form based on the redirect URL?

My other thought is to have all the login in options on the main login page, and switch between them depending on if the redirect URL is Part A or Part B, but this seems inelegant.

Is that the only way?

Comment: Something so simple as checking if the `dropdownlist` on form B is empty or not and redirect accordingly doesn't seem that inelegant.

Comment: @iamdlm the dropdown list isn't the determiner, it's the redirect URL. Hard coding a redirect seems more inelegant to me than having a way to configure multiple logins, but if that's all there is, I'll do it.

Comment: so the first question , how will u differentiate the users ? like who should go with normal login page , and who will go with the dropdown option ?

Comment: The users for partA will follow a link to partA, and the same for partB